# c++ throw with try catch all always hits terminate in C++ 11 14 and 17

Tags: c++, try-catch, terminate, throw

I keep getting terminate called for anything I throw using GCC 9.2, even if it is caught.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
terminate called recursively
```

I have tested -std=c++17, -std=c++14, -std=c++11

Example test:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  try
  {
      throw "not found";
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't fail if i compile using visual studio or on multiple of the online compilers.
example:
https://repl.it/languages/cpp
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

I have also tried putting the throw in a function and adding noexcept(false), but this fails as well. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() noexcept(false)
{
    throw std::runtime_error( "test1" );
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
      foo();
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Edit:

System info:

I'm using 9-2020-q2-update - arm-linux-none-gnueabihf.

Basically, the setup is Linux x86 as my main computer, cross compiling for ARM Cortex-A processor. The processor i'm testing are Raspberry Pi 4 and BeagleBone Black.

The code compiles correctly and runs fine on the target processor, except when an exception is hit. At which point, it hits terminate for any throw.

I'm using Eclipse as the IDE, using remote debug to upload and step through the code on either of the target processors.

Comment: Please add details about the system you're getting this result on.

Comment: I have tried both `repl.it` and Godbolt, both of which print out `test` exactly as they should. There is nothing wrong with your code, but probably with your compiler flags.

Comment: yah that is what i'm thinking as well. It must be a compiler flag missing or something. I've tried -fexceptions, but this didn't work.

Comment: @user2654735 Can you reproduce it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/foThEE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug or exception handling isn't working on version 9.2 of GCC (ARM only?) compiler.

I tried with version 8.3-2019.03 - arm-linux-gnueabihf - Linux x86 compiler and they are working just fine. No other changes were necessary, other than the compile switch.

https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads